# Когда стоит использовать в качестве параметров функции указатели, а когда переменные?

Tags: c++, указатели

Зависит ли это от количества переменных? От того какого они типа? Как использовать указатели для прироста производительности?

Answer (score 5):

### Рекомендации из [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html).

Рекомендации ниже основаны на стайлгайде от Google, но по факту они чуть жёстче, их чуть дополнил Yandex.

1. Если вы передаёте переменную, размер которой не очень велик, например это стандартный тип, наподобие `int`, `double`, `bool`, и эта переменная подразумевается параметром функции (а не предназначена для изменения из функции) - передавайте её **по значению**.
2. Если вы передаёте переменную, в которую будете сохранять часть ответа (или весь ответ), то передавайте её **через указатель**.
3. Если вы передаёте переменную-класс, или просто тяжеловесную переменную, передавайте её **по константной ссылке** (чтобы избежать накладных расходов на копирование переменной).
4. Если неизвестен тип передаваемой переменной-параметра (например это параметр шаблона), передавайте её **по константной ссылке**.
5. Передачу параметров **по неконстантной ссылке** Google рекомендует не использовать вовсе.

Comment: Неконстантные ссылки они вообще не любят. Довольно спорный style guide.

Comment: Поддерживаю, но как первый этап для какой-то стилизации кода сойдёт. Мне например их полный отказ от исключений не очень нравится... И там ещё немало подобных спорных решений. Но часто лучше хоть какой-то порядок, чем тот бардак, что часто пишут новички :)

Comment: Почти никогда: In fact it is a very strong convention in Google code that input arguments are values or const references while output arguments are pointers. Input parameters may be const pointers, but we never allow non-const reference parameters except when required by convention, e.g., swap().

Comment: @Qwertiy, `неконстантные ссылки они вообще не любят` — ибо побочные эффекты и их дальнейший поиск и учёт в большой и запутанной системе. Вход на вход, выход на выход  за маленьким исключением в виде this, который по области действия сильно ограничен (за пределы класса не вылезает), а потому как бы легко отслеживается.

Comment: @ߊߚߤߘ, да, это имеет смысл. С другой стороны, разработчики stl ведь в том же swap пошли другим путём. Мне кажется, тут скорее вопрос правильности именования функций, чем неправильности способа передачи.

Answer (score 1):

```
void foo(Type* ptr, /*...*/)
```

Читая это обьявление, можно догадаться, что функция обрабатывает последовательность или функция учитывает возможность обрабатывать не только обьекты типа  `Type`, но и обьекты его дочерных типов.

Решение, передать в аргумент указатель, абсолютно не зависит от количества обьектов(старайтесь говорить об обьектах, а не о переменных).
Зависит от типа, только если, как я выше указал, тип может иметь свои производные, и нам нужно рассматривать передачу в функцию обьектов таких типов тоже.

Как использовать указатель для прироста производительности, по моему слышком общий вопрос: все зависит от кода и задачи, который он выполняет. Во всяком случаи, в рудиментарных кодах и в кодах обрабатывающие последовательность, деревья, связные списки и т.д. и т.п. без использования указателей не обойтись.

В общем случаи, если вы хотите выразить: "мне нужен  и этот и тот и вон тот тоже", это именно указатели, а если вы хотите выразить: "для игры, мне   нужен ваш мяч, и его мяч и мой  тоже", то вы работаете с конкретными обьектами...

Comment: я бы не догадался про последовательность, если последовательность, то где-то должен быть и size

Comment: @goldstar_labs,  речь о том, когда может быть в аргументе указатель, а не о том, что аргумент должен быть один, во вторых функция вполне может быть шаблонным, в параметрах которого указывается размер, а в третьих  , например, для символьных массивов, можно  размер определить в функции

Comment: @goldstar_labs, так или иначе,  считаю ваше замечание уместным,   поэтому внес маленькую поправку в своем ответе, а вам спасибо...